# Can you compute Laplacian, divergence, curl for a function?

Tags: laplacian, divergence-operator, curl, divergence-theorem

In my physics class, we are currently studying gradient, Laplacian, divergence, and curl, and we have a problem that states to compute all four of these (I.e., (1) gradient, (2) Laplacian, (3) divergence, and (4) curl) “as appropriate” for the given expressions.

Now I noticed that some of the expressions are vectors and some are not. I’ve been reading about divergence and curl and know somewhat how they apply to vectors, vector fields. But do they apply to functions as well?

Likewise, how can you take the partial derivative of a vector?

Of note, I understand that the gradient and curl can be zero but here I am talking not about one of these operations being zero but rather about possibly not being able to do it at all.

For example, the first problem is computing “as appropriate” the gradient, Laplacian, divergence and curl of x^2+ysinz. Is it possible to provide a hint as to which of these would be possible to do and why/how?

Finally, I did originally ask this question in the Physics forum but was advised to ask here instead.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think "as appropriate" means, if it doesn't make sense, don't do it. So don't compute the curl or divergence, as those need vector fields as input

Comment: Thank you so much! That is so helpful! I was considering that since they aren’t functions, but expressions, maybe there’s a corresponding vector field - so that isn’t the case? Thank you again.

Comment: there are ways to make vector fields from it (e.g. take the gradient!) but if they don't tell you how to make a vector field, I wouldn't :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. With this class, we’ve been studying vector fields a lot - but with curl and divergence. I don’t think we covered Laplacian and I’m not sure if the Laplacian is just the second derivative of the gradient? Although watching videos helps, I’m having some trouble understanding the notation. Thanks again!

Comment: Or it is the dot product of the gradient times the gradient? It’s probably a silly question but I am just getting a little confused by the “S” notation. Thank you!

Comment: The Laplacian $\Delta$ is the divergence of the gradient. Its sometimes written as $\nabla^2$ because it is equal to $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$ which looks like the "squared norm" of $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z})$

Comment: I’m also having some trouble understanding the difference between the divergence and the gradient? So the gradient is for non-vectors and the divergence is the equivalent for vectors?

Comment: divergence takes a vector field, and returns a scalar field. Gradient takes a scalar field and outputs a vector field (or a vector field and outputs the jacobian matrix). This is getting past the scope of your original question

Comment: Thanks! You’re just so helpful. I’m still a little bit confused but working through more practice problems and will start a follow-up question, if that’s okay.

Comment: If you want to ask more small questions of this sort that don't need a full question written up on the site, you could try a chat room. I tried to make one [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110884/calvins-chat-room), and will be there occasionally (hopefully more often, but I'm busy). There is also a [Mathematics chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)

Comment: Thank you! I didn’t know that! That’s very generous of you. Hope that you have a good night.